# repeating an equation and getting the same equation number?

Tags: numbering

Let's say I have written an equation in my paper and numbered it:

```
y = a + bx    (1)
```

Then, later in the paper, I want to remind the reader by showing the same equation **with the same equation number**.

Sure, I can repeat the equation, but LaTeX gives it a new equationn number:

```
y = a + bx     (2)
```

How do I force LaTeX to use the original equation numbers?

Comment: I'm not sure whether I wouldn't be confused by such thing in a document, because when I search for a specific eq. number, I simply follow the numbers on the border and this makes a mess there. What you want to achieve is similar to including a term "foo" between "bar" and "baz" in a dictionary. I would recommend you to say it only in the text: "Let us recall the equation (1): ..."

Comment: Kind of duplicate of this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33750/586 Same question, except that in that case a LyX answer was asked for. (A LaTeX answer is also given.)

Answer (score 110):

Use the `\label`, `\ref` mechanism; once you have `\label`led the equation you can use `\ref` inside `\tag` to retrieve the number:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:test}
a = b + c.
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
a = b + c. \tag{\ref{eq:test}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As **Niel de Beaudrap** mentions in his comment, one way to avoid equation numbering confusion for the reader would be to add "revisited" to the tag of the duplicated equation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:test}
a = b + c.
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
a = b + c. \tag{\ref{eq:test} revisited}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Small addition:
Use `equation*` in stead of `equation` when repeating the number so that LaTeX knows it should not use a new number. This avoids warnings when using e.g. the `hyperref` package. Thus:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:test}
a = b + c.
\end{equation}

\begin{equation*}
a = b + c. \tag{\ref{eq:test} revisited}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Same as http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33750/using-the-same-number-for-repeated-use-of-the-same-equation

Comment: Using _unstarred_ `align` instead of `equation*` doesn't give me any `hyperref` warning and skips the number properly [i.e.,  (1), (1 revisited), (2), ...].

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Is there a way not to have to type the whole thing again? It seems kinda silly to type it again, not to mention error prone. Thanks for your excellent answer btw.

Comment: @tBuLi But you do not need to type it again. Just copy paste it!

Comment: @tBuLi you can define a new command that types your equation like `\newcommand{\myeq}{a + b = y}`. Then call it with `\myeq`. That way, if you need to correct your equation, you just need to do it in one place.

Comment: This recipe does not work for beamer... :\

Comment: @PedroH.N.Vieira: It's workable, but defining new commands gets messy if you have many.